# nodejs stream readable stuck at first readable object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js

I have a [NodeJS stream.Readable](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable):

```
var async = require('async'),
    util = require('util'),
    ReadableStream = require('readable-stream').Readable;

function ArticleReader() {
  ReadableStream.call(this, { objectMode: true });
}

util.inherits(ArticleReader, ReadableStream);

ArticleReader.prototype._read = function() {
    var articles = ['article1', 'article2'];
    var self = this;
    async.each(articles, function(link, callback) {
       self.push(article);
       callback();
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            self.emit('error', err);
        } else {
            self.push(null);
        }
    });
};
```

And this is the consumer:

```
var article = new ArticleReader();

  article.on('readable', function() {
  var buf = article.read();
  console.log(buf);
});

article.on('end', function() {
  console.log('end');
});
```

Here's the output:

```
'article1'
```

The problem is program is stuck at `'article1'`, it never reads `'article2'`, and it never reaches `end` event too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the event `end` fires when there **will be no more data** to read.

Also the `end` event **will not fire** unless the data is completely consumed. This can be done by switching into `flowing mode`, or by calling `read()` repeatedly until you get to the end.

The solution, was to keep reading until the end of the stream is reached.

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();

readable.on('readable', function() {
  while ((buf = readable.read()) != null) {
    console.log(buf);
  }
}

readable.on('data', function(chunk) {
  console.log('got %d bytes of data', chunk.length);
})
readable.on('end', function() {
  console.log('there will be no more data.');
});
```

Comment: oh now I understand, if I listen to `data` event, it's on flowing-mode, and I don't need to keep reading in a while loop, thanks.